# Import "rest_framework.decorators" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

This is my first time using the djando rest framework. I've installed it but when i try to import the following in my views.py file in django, i get an error

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
```

The error I get is

```
Import "rest_framework.decorators" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having this same issue using VSCode. The issue for me was VSCode was picking the incorrect Python interpreter for my project. I am running a pipenv but VSCode was not using it.

The fix for me was to go to `View -> Command Palette` or `Ctrl+shift+p` and type `Python Select Interpreter` And select the correct interpreter for my project.

[image: VSCode Python Select Interpreter]

Answer (score 0):

It all worked well. The best response, you will have to select the right python path to solve the issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u5N0.png)

Thank you.

Comment: and what is the "right" interpreter?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35595056)